# kadirahq/mup fails on verifying deployment

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, digital-ocean, meteor-up

I'm trying to deploy my app using [`kadirahq/mup`](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up), on Ubuntu `16.04`, to a Digital Ocean droplet also running Ubuntu `16.04`.
My app is at Meteor `1.4.1.1`, and reports using node `4.5.0`.
My machine's node version is at `6.6.0`.

I read the [mup faq](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up#faq) and tried to increase the `deployCheckWaitTime`, and have tried it with values as high as `2000`, with no change.

I have successfully deployed this app to this droplet before using older versions of `mup` and `mupx`, but started having problems and decided to upgrade to the new version.

I am also having prompts about `js-bson`, which I've documented here and seem perhaps related:
[Meteor: js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650617/meteor-js-bson-failed-to-load-c-bson-extension-using-pure-js-version)

I was originally using `dockerImage: 'kadirahq/meteord'`, but after reading [this issue comment by abernix](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7475#issuecomment-235229269) I changed it to `dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base'`, which successfully solved that issue but replaced it with this one.

When I run `mup setup`, everything runs successfully.
`mup deploy` runs all of the steps successfully until the Verifying Deployment step:

```
(node:2785) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error:
```

It spits out the above, and then a bunch of stuff that's also spit out in the logs, so I've put that below.

The output of `mup logs --tail=200` is huge and changes every time I run it, but here's a reduction of what I more or less think it's repeating:

```
Error: $ROOT_URL, if specified, must be an URL
        at Error (native)
        at packages/meteor/url_server.js:8:1
        at packages/meteor/url_server.js:19:1
        at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:1365:3
        at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:292:10
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Function._.each._.forEach (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
        at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:128:5

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server
> node npm-rebuild.js


> bson@0.2.21 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
bson.target.mk:94: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o' failed
make: Leaving directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build'

> kerberos@0.0.9 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
kerberos.target.mk:100: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o' failed
make: Leaving directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/cfs_gridfs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build'

// references to a million node modules

> bcrypt@0.8.7 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
make: Leaving directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
bcrypt@0.8.7 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt

// references to a million different node modules

{
  "meteor-dev-bundle": "0.0.0",
  "npm": "3.10.5",
  "ares": "1.10.1-DEV",
  "http_parser": "2.5.2",
  "icu": "56.1",
  "modules": "46",
  "node": "4.4.7",
  "openssl": "1.0.2h",
  "uv": "1.8.0",
  "v8": "4.5.103.36",
  "zlib": "1.2.8"
}
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.
=> Starting meteor app on port:80
/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:333
}).run();
```

Here are the relevant portions of my `.deploy/mup.js` file:

```
meteor: {
    name: 'boxes',
    path: '/home/blaine/Business/Boxes/boxes/',
    servers: {
        one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
        serverOnly: true,
    },
    env: {
        ROOT_URL: 'example.com',
        MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor'
    },

    // dockerImage: 'kadirahq/meteord'
    dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    deployCheckWaitTime: 60
},

mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
        one: {},
    },
},
```

I've also tried to remove the bcrypt package both my running `meteor npm uninstall bcrypt` and by removing it from my `package.json` dependencies: `"bcrypt": "^0.8.7"`, and verifying it was gone by looking at my node_modules directory. I replaced it with the [meteor bcrypt package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/npm-bcrypt). No change.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was much simpler than it seemed. The large node module related output was a bit of a red herring, and I assumed it was that. However, the relevant part was this: `Error: $ROOT_URL, if specified, must be an URL`.

My `ROOT_URL` didn't have the `http://` protocol included. Adding it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For future google hits, I would like to add that your deployment machine resources (RAM, CPU) will play part in wether you are able to successfully deploy.

My problem was the size of my digital ocean droplet, but the error when trying to deploy was not intuitive in any way..